# Setting model and associated actions with Bootstrap modals and Ember 1.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

### Preface

See Edit#1 for updated code based upon first answer and a jsbin.

I am trying to integrate Bootstrap modals into an Ember app. I have an id called main-modal-content and want to write in templates to that id. I have the following controller:

```
App.InventoryItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    showModal: function(){
    var item=this.get('model');
    var source   = $("#ii-edit").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html_str    = template(item);
    $('#main-modal-content').html(html_str);    
    $('#myModal').modal(); 
   },
    saveInventoryItem: function(){
      alert('now to save!!!');  
    }
  },

  isExpanded:false  
});][1]
```

and this template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="ii-edit">
     here is my edit {{id}}  <div {{action 'saveInventoryItem' target='InventoryItemController'}}>save inventory item</div>
  </script>
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

How do I set a reference to target back to InventoryItemController so that saveInventoryItem can be called? Also, this is just a first pass - does this seem like a reasonable way to do modals in Ember?

### Edit #1

Here's an example of trying to maintain a reference to the open modal: http://jsbin.com/tabor/2/edit

I've updated an Application route with this but it's unclear how to set the model for the specific controller in question - or perhaps this route needs to be returning the model?:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modalName, object) {
      this.controller.set('model', object);  // <- this is not working
      this.set('model',object);  // <- this also isn't working

      this.render(modalName, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal',
        controller: 'modal' 
      });

      if($('#myModal')){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
      console.log('after this');

    },
    closeModal: function() {
    //return this.disconnectOutlet({

    this.disconnectOutlet({
      outlet: 'modal',
      parentView: 'application'

    });
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    }
   },
  });
```

Adding this to the above Route doesn't help:

```
        // even hardcoding this isn't working!!!!
  model:function(){
     //return this.get('object');
     return Em.Object.create({id: 7, name: 'Jon'});
    }
```

And the template:

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myModal">
      <div>
       id val: {{id}}
        <button {{action 'sayHello' id }}>Say Hello</button>

       </div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the cookbook](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) for an easier way.

It involves having a `modal` outlet somewhere probably in your application template and using a route's `render` method to insert a template into it:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modalName) {
      return this.render(modalName, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    },

    closeModal: function() {
     return this.disconnectOutlet({
       outlet: 'modal',
       parentView: 'application'
     });
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm... so while I see that, how would I associate myModal with a specific oebject / controller?

Comment: got passing  `controller: 'modal'` for ModalController